# yii2 не открывается главная страница

Tags: yii2

Установил данный фрэйм на винду (OPEN_SERVER), и сегодня обнаружил данную проблему:
Ввожу запрос  http://yii2.loc/web/index.php  данный запрос обрабатывается несколько минут и затем вылетает ошибка. В чем может быть проблема скажите пожалуйста. Вчера все работало почему-то.

Comment: смотрите логи, там написано в чем ошибка

Comment: Посмотрел логи апач-запросов и их нет, ну я делаю запрос, а он даже в логе не отображается. Хотя если делаю запрос на другой свой локальный сайт то запрос отображается

Comment: [Fri Jul 05 20:17:03.698663 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 6156:tid 232] AH01909: yii2.loc:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: А это логи апач отладки - там все логи такие однотипные как показано выше и причем ко всем моим проектам локальным.